# /usr/sbin/fsck.xfs: XFS file system ubuntu boot message

Tags: kernel

Today I have run a liberaoffice command from my terminal. after that my laptop goes hang. I restart my pc and I am unable to login . Just shows this message "/usr/sbin/fsck.xfs: XFS file system" What Can I do now ?

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqQPg.png)

Comment: I'd boot a *live* Ubuntu system and perform a `xfs_check`.   `fsck` cannot perform checks on XFS and just exits on most systems (you've not provided any release details; but chances are this will apply with your *unstated* system too)   On my own release the man page states "*fsck.xfs  is called by the generic Linux fsck(8) program at startup to check and repair an XFS filesystem.  XFS is a journaling filesystem and performs recovery at mount(8) time if necessary, so fsck.xfs simply exits with a zero exit status.*"   Once done, assuming an error is detected/fixed; you'll find it boots normally

Comment: Me too.   I got it today (Jun 2022).